# ie11 Attempt to use the method flat() polyfill causes error within the polyfill

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have been getting error in my code saying that

```
object does not support function or method split
```

The function causing the error is as follows:

```
function convertSpecial(a,b,c) {
var aCopy = a.split("");
for (var i = 0; i < aCopy.length; i++) {
    if (aCopy[i].includes(b)) {
        if (c == '') {
            aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c);
        } else {
            aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c).split(' ');
            aCopy = aCopy.flat();
        }
    }
}

return aCopy;
}
```

I've assumed that this error is happening because of the use of .flat() in my code.

However, the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) doesn't work either. I'm getting an error saying that an ; is expected on this line:

```
for (var el of array) {
```

The Babel fix below also doesn't solve my porblem. Using the below, I still get the object does not support the method split error.

```
if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
Array.prototype.flat = function (depth) {
var flattened = [];

(function flat(array, depth) {
  var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
  var _didIteratorError = false;
  var _iteratorError = undefined;

  try {
    for (var _iterator = array[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
      var el = _step.value;

      if (Array.isArray(el) && depth > 0) {
        flat(el, depth - 1);
      } else {
        flattened.push(el);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
  } finally {
    try {
      if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return != null) {
        _iterator.return();
      }
    } finally {
      if (_didIteratorError) {
        throw _iteratorError;
      }
    }
  }
})(this, Math.floor(depth) || 1);

return flattened;
};
}
```

So what is possibly causing my problem?

Comment: Is it because IE does not support `for...of`?  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Possibly. So what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!

```
function convertSpecial(a,b,c) {
var aCopy = a.toString().split("");
for (var i = 0; i < aCopy.length; i++) {
if (aCopy[i].includes(b)) {
    if (c == '') {
        aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c);
    } else {
        aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c).toString().split(' ');
        aCopy = aCopy.flat();
    }
}
}

return aCopy;
}
```

Comment: Turns out the variables have to be force converted toString().

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support ES6+ features, including `for..of`, so the polyfill as given does not work.

Reading the [proposal specification](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/#sec-Array.prototype.flat):

> 1. Let targetIndex be start.
> 2. Let sourceIndex be 0.
> 3. Repeat, while sourceIndex < sourceLen

Arrays are iterated over starting from index 0, incrementing by 1 until the length is reached. So, rather than messing with iterators (IE does not understand `Symbol`), use a plain `for` loop instead to increment manually.

Because the given polyfill depends on `Array.isArray`, make sure to polyfill it as well.

The following snippet runs as expected on IE11:

```js
console.log(
  [1, [2, 3]].flat()
);
```

```html
<script>
// Also polyfill Array.isArray:
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Polyfill
if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
  Array.prototype.flat = function(depth) {
    var flattened = [];
    (function flat(array, depth) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var el = array[i];
        if (Array.isArray(el) && depth > 0) {
          flat(el, depth - 1); 
        } else {
          flattened.push(el);
        }
      }
    })(this, Math.floor(depth) || 1);
    return flattened;
  };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well your code stops ie from complaining about the polyfill but I’m back to having the error saying that split is not supported.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, `split` isn't even anywhere in the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU5lv.png

Comment: Oh, you changed the question significantly. Please do not ask [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). What are you calling `convertSpecial` with, and what is the expected output?

Comment: no, I just added the function that was causing the error. I didn't change the question at all. I'm calling the function like this: var special = convertSpecial(arrayln,"-'"," ");I initially assumed it was the polyfill causing the error, but turns out that was a false assumption.

Comment: What is `arrayln`, the first argument? (Need a [MCVE] to reproduce the problem) The polyfill *was* actually causing that error, since it was using `for..of`. It looks to be also mixing `let` and `var`, would definitely benefit from some fixing, I hope MDN will permit an edit to it

Comment: No it wasn’t. The polyfill was a pre-requisite to solve the original error. The error was happening before the polyfill existed. The polyfill introduced a second error because it was using for..of. With the second error solved by the Babel code, as posted in the question, we were still left with the original error which, as it turns out, was being caused because the array of strings had to first be converted into a string for IE11, while in chrome and Firefox this was not an issue